# If $a$ is sufficiently large as compared with $b,$ and $\sqrt \frac{a}{a-b}+\sqrt \frac{a}{a+b}=2+k(\frac{b}{a})^2$,then what is the value of $k?$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

> If  $a$ is sufficiently large as compared with $b,$ and $\sqrt
>  \frac{a}{a-b}+\sqrt \frac{a}{a+b}=2+k(\frac{b}{a})^2$,then what is the
> value of $k?$

### Query

Can we find it using particular value?,like putting $a=4,b=2,$ then we get

> **$k=4\sqrt2+4\sqrt \frac{2}{3}-8$**

This problem is given in  Multiple Choice Question exercise,the possible answers given are

A.$\frac{2}{3}$

B.$\frac{3}{4}$

C.$\frac{4}{5}$

D.$\frac{5}{6}$

None of the answer mathches with mine....

Please give some hint to determine value of $k?$

Comment: The tags are irrelevant. Binomial approximation is to be used.

Comment: **Hint**: $(1+x)^{n}\approx 1+nx$ for $|x|\lt1$

Comment: What do you mean "a sufficiently larger than b"? Do you mean as $a \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @SenZen:No idea about this phrase,assumed  it simply as $a>b$

Comment: It means that $b/a\approx0$

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Negative Binomial Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html).

$(1-a/b)^{-1/2}+(1+a/b)^{-1/2}=2+2\left(\frac{a}b\right)^2\left[\binom{-1/2}2+\binom{-1/2}4\left(\frac{a}b\right)^2+\binom{-1/2}6\left(\frac{a}b\right)^4+...\right]$

Since we want $k$ (constant) to be independent of $a/b$, we reject the higher order terms in the bracket on the ground that $a>>b$, giving $k=2\binom{-1/2}2=(-1/2)\times(-1/2-1)=3/4$.

---

Note that with the obtained $k$, $(1-a/b)^{-1/2}+(1+a/b)^{-1/2}\approx2+k(a/b)^2$ i.e. $(1-a/b)^{-1/2}+(1+a/b)^{-1/2}$ is not actually equal to $2+k(a/b)^2$ in general. As you have seen, for equality $k$ will have to be taken as a function of $a,b$ and not constant. Thus plugging in specific values of $a,b$ to find $k$ (which gives the exact value of $k$) will not yield the desired answer.

If you wanted to take a risk, you could check which option for $k$ yields the closest answer to the value of $(1-a/b)^{-1/2}+(1+a/b)^{-1/2}$ for the selected $a,b$. But remember that you still might not get $k=3/4$ since it is not necessary that $3/4$ gives the closest approximation of $(1-a/b)^{-1/2}+(1+a/b)^{-1/2}$ for **all** $a,b$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that for small $\epsilon$:

$$(1+\epsilon)^{-1/2}=1+\binom{-1/2}{1}\epsilon+\binom{-1/2}{2}{\epsilon^2}+O(\epsilon^3)=1-\frac12\epsilon+\frac{3}{8}\epsilon^2+O(\epsilon^3)$$

If you put $-\epsilon$ instead of $\epsilon$ into the last expression you get:

$$(1-\epsilon)^{-1/2}=1+\frac12\epsilon+\frac{3}{8}e^2+O(\epsilon^3)$$

It means that:

$$(1+\epsilon)^{-1/2}+(1-\epsilon)^{-1/2}=2+\frac34\epsilon^2+O(\epsilon^3)$$

If you put $\epsilon=b/a$, you are done. Obviously $k=\frac34$